# rowCount(), Why doesnt it work on create user ? Any options?

Tags: php, mysql, createuser

Creating new user in mysql as :

```
$query = $dbconnection->prepare("CREATE USER 'john'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass'");
$query->execute();
$counts = $query->rowCount();
return $counts;
```

Generally in other queries, I use rowCount() to check whether the query got successful or not. if rowCount() >1, query successful. But I realised this doesnt work in creating user.

In this case, user is created, but rowCount() still results the value 0. Is there any way, to check whether this query is successful.

UPDATE in @GHOST comment: 
   This query returns the value 1, to confirm that data is inserted, or a row is affected.

```
     $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO agent(uname,password,) VALUES(?,?");    
    $values = array($uname,$pw);
    $query->execute($values);
    $counts=$query->rowCount();
    return $counts;
```

I am looking for some way, to check in same way for the previous case.

Comment: We are going to need to see a lot more code than this? Is this just solely a sql query?

Comment: i don't think rowcount can be applied to data definitions. it doesn't make sense

Comment: @Ghost, I hope the update will make it more clear.

Comment: @ColinSchoen, More code added. Should be much clear now.

Comment: You can check return of errorCode() method

Comment: might as well just check if `->execute()` returns true for data definitions, it wouldn't make sense trying to check how many rows yielded since it didn't manipulate anything. its already in the manual: `returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the additional code

`$query->execute();` This will return True on a successful query and False if there was an error when executing the query

```
if !($query->execute() {
    echo "Ouch, there was an error.";
}
```

Comment: If this used exception errmode you you don't can check return of execute

Comment: @Deep, sure, but that would be the case for anything.  You wouldn't get to rowCount() either if an exception was thrown.  If you use the exception mode on PDO, then you should be using `try catch` blocks.

Comment: @Devon yes, and? Are you sure that author not use single global try catch? And maybe use it tomorrow?

Comment: @Deep, there is nothing to suggest that and exceptions are not the default for PDO, so I don't think it is fair to assume that especially considering the author suggests he relies on the return value to see if the query succeeded thus making it fair to assume the opposite of what you are saying because with PDO exceptions, it would never get to the return if the query failed.

Comment: @Devon ok, ok - just this is my paranoid mode ))

Answer (score 1):

Colin's answer is correct for the standard PDO error mode.

This is more of a long comment than an answer but it is important to make note of the differences of return values for `rowCount()` and `execute()` especially for updates and deletes.

When you update and delete, you can have a `rowCount()` of `0` but an `execute()` of `true`.  This means that the query succeeded but no rows matched the constraints provided (usually `WHERE`).

Therefore, when performing updates and deletes, you should be checking both return values.  One to make sure the query succeeded and one to check to see if rows were affected.  Checking for both will make debugging easier and prevent a fatal error on `rowCount()` if the query fails.

Comment: Agreed. Though, I was looking for alternative solution to check whether the query has been successful on "creating User", colin's answer might be the best solution. So far so good. Answer accepted.